# Android SQ Lite - How to insert more than 1000 rows at a time efficiently?

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic-framework, sql-insert, large-data

I am using Ionic Framework. I want to ask for help about how to insert more than 1000 rows at a time and while insertion showing a loading spinner to user so that there wont be any mess in database.

First, I have two services/factories.

Database :

```
.factory('DB', function ($ionicPopup, $cordovaSQLite, $q, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaNetwork,$ionicLoading) {
        var self = this;
        self.query = function (query, parameters) {
            parameters = parameters || [];
            var q = $q.defer();
            $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
                $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, parameters)
                    .then(function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                        q.resolve(result);
                    }, function (error) {
                        console.log(error+"  .."+error.message);
                        alert('I found an error' + error.message);
                        q.reject(error);
                    });
            });
            return q.promise;
        }
        // Proces a result set
        self.getAll = function (result) {
            var output = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                output.push(result.rows.item(i));
            }
            return output;
        }
        // Proces a single result
        self.getById = function (result) {
            var output = null;
            output = angular.copy(result.rows.item(0));
            return output;
        }
        return self;
    })
```

Secondly, AsyncService for downloading data from multiple urls

```
.service('asyncService', function ($http, $q) {
        return {
            loadDataFromUrls: function (urls) {
                alert("I am inside new Service ");
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var urlCalls = [];
                angular.forEach(urls, function (url) {
                    urlCalls.push($http.get(url.url));
                });
                // they may, in fact, all be done, but this
                // executes the callbacks in then, once they are
                // completely finished.
                $q.all(urlCalls)
                    .then(
                    function (results) {
                        deferred.resolve(results)
                    },
                    function (errors) {
                        console.log(errors);
                        deferred.reject(errors);
                    },
                    function (updates) {
                        console.log(updates);
                        deferred.update(updates);
                    });
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };
    })
```

And the method that firstly, should download the datas and then insert them into their belonged tables.

```
asyncService.loadDataFromUrls(urLs).then(function (result) {
                DB.query("DELETE FROM INV");
                // when i have to update the tables, i first delete them and then fill them back again.
                $ionicLoading.show({
                    template : 'Processing into Database. Please Wait...',
                    timeout : '6000'                      
                });
                result.forEach(function (rows) {
                    console.log(rows.config.url);
                    var i = 0;
                    if (rows.config.url == 'http://11.444.222.55:55/mobil_op?op=get_inv') {
                        rows.data.forEach(function (entry) {
                            var parameters = [entry.code, entry.name,];
                            DB.query("INSERT INTO INV (CODE,NAME,......) VALUES(?,?........)",parameters);
                        })
                    }
                })

            }, function (err) {
                alert("OOpsss ! : " + err.message);
                console.log("error");
            }, function (updates) {
                alert("updates");
                console.log("updates" + updates);
            })
```

How should I work while inserting 4453 elements into array ?

Comment: Which is your bottleneck? Downloading the data or inserting the data? 4453  elements is not that many rows. Is there a lot of data?

Comment: Yeah i have two huge tables and the other 4 ones are small ones. The data that i have to download for one huge table is around 12Megabytes(4453 elements in that json array  ). In the above example, i only showed one huge table example because a lot of code can mislead the point.

Comment: You should package a prepopulate database with apk

Comment: Sam, can you be more specific please ? :)

Comment: If you only need the large data on installation then you can include static files in your apk. Then you can just download the delta. If you need to refresh regularly then it won't work.

Comment: For example, the user has to download these tables( the large data set) once a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
db.executeSql("BEGIN TRANSACTION",{})
  .then(( res )=> { 
    console.log(res);
   // DO ALL INSERTION ON THE TABLES
   // e.g

    // AT LAST 
  db.executeSql("COMMIT",{})
    .then(()=> console.log("COMMIT")
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
    
  }).catch(e => console.log(e));

// This process provided me much more faster way . The method above in the question dialog was inserting 4553 items in 3 minutes on Asus Zenphone 1. This method let me insert 10000 items less then 3 minutes.
```